# A formula expressing that $ m = \sum^n_{i=1} i^n $

Tags: first-order-logic

Write a such formula $\phi(x,y) $ in arithmetic language that
$(\mathbb{N}, x : n, y : m) \models \phi(x,y) \iff m = \sum^n_{i = 1}i^n $

So why cannot I write: $\phi (x,y): y = 1^x + 2^x + 3^x + .. + x^x$

But it seems to be too simple.

Comment: Are you looking for a "closed" formula for $y:=y(x)$ ?

Comment: The language of arithmetic doesn't include a symbol for the operation $x^y,$ and, more fundamentally, first-order logic doesn't include the notation $"\!\dots\!".$

Comment: Ok, so please help me.

Comment: @Logic So what are you allowed to use here when you say 'arithmetical language'? Are you allowed to use an exponent function as part of your language? If not, then this is quite difficult to do (see Mitchell's answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in summation operation in first order logic, or anything dealing with a series of variable length. So, you want to do this recursively:

Define a function $sum(z,x)$ that you want to be $\sum^z_{i=1} i^x$ as follows:

$\forall x \: sum(1,x)=1$

$\forall z \forall x \: sum(s(z),x) = sum(z,x) + s(z)^x$

Here, $s(z)$ is the successor of $z$, i.e. $z+1$, and it is also assumed you have a function $x^y$ ... You can refer to the axioms of Peano Arithmetic here if needed, where the power function can be defined recursively similar to how addition and multiplication are defined recursively:

$\forall x \: x^0 = 1$

$\forall x \forall y \: x^{s(y)}=x^y * x$

With the above $sum(z,x)$ function, you can define your $\phi (x,y)$ as follows:

$\forall x \forall y (\phi(x,y) \leftrightarrow y = sum(x,x))$

Comment: You can't define functions like that in the language of arithmetic either...

Comment: Because the language of arithmetic only contains the symbols $0$, $s$, $+$, and $*$? But if we can only use those, then I see no other way to deal with variable length series other than using some kind of godel encoding of series of numbers ... Somehow I doubt that the OP has to go through that effort!  But you're right, we should get clear on what the OP is and is not allowed to use.

Answer (score 0):

Actually getting a first-order formula in arithmetic that expresses this is a bit long and unwieldy:

If this is a homework assignment, I presume you have covered in class some way of coding arbitrarily long finite sequences of natural numbers as natural numbers. (This can be done, for example, using prime decomposition or via Cantor's pairing function.)  In developing this, you would get first order formulas that are equivalent to \begin{align}"\!x\text{ codes}&\text{ a finite sequence of length }y\!",\tag{1}
\\"\!x\text{ codes}&\text{ a finite sequence, }\\&y\text{ is less than the length of that finite sequence,}\\&\text{and }z\text{ is the }y^{\text{th}}\text{ element in that finite sequence (starting the indexing at }0)\!",\tag{2}\end{align}
etc.

You can then write $x=y^z$ as:

\begin{align}(\exists w)\Big((w&\text{ codes a finite sequence of length }z+1)\;\land
\\&\text{(the }0^\text{th}\text{ element of that finite sequence}=1)\;\land
\\&(\text{the }z^\text{th}\text{ element of that finite sequence}=x)\;\land
\\&(\forall v)\big(v\lt z \rightarrow(y\cdot(\text{the }v^\text{th}\text{ element of the sequence coded by }w)=(\text{the }(v+1)^\text{st}\text{ element of the sequence coded by }w)\big)\Big).
\end{align}

In a similar fashion, and using the formula for $x=y^z$ above, you can write a first-order formula in arithmetic that expresses $m = \sum^n_{i = 1}i^n$ as:

\begin{align}
(\exists w)\Big((w&\text{ codes a finite sequence of length }n+1)\;\land
\\&\text{(the }0^\text{th}\text{ element of that finite sequence}=0)\;\land
\\&(\text{the }n^\text{th}\text{ element of that finite sequence}=m)\;\land
\\&(\forall v)\big(v\lt n \rightarrow (\exists u)\big((u=i^{v+1})\land
\\&\hphantom{\big(v\lt n \rightarrow (\exists u)\big((u=i}u+(\text{the }v^\text{th}\text{ element of the sequence coded by }w)
\\&\hphantom{\big(v\lt n \rightarrow (\exists u)\big((u=i)\big)}=(\text{the }(v+1)^\text{st}\text{ element of the sequence coded by }w)\big)\big)\Big).
\end{align}

Expand everything out in full and you'll get a first-order formula of arithmetic with the property you wanted.